# Spyder/Python - Automatically set working directory to current script's

Tags: python, directory, spyder

I know that the directory can be automatically changed to that of the current script if we press F5.

But is there a way to automatically do so when I run the codes in interactive mode, or when I open a script? Currently I need to os.chdir() to the current working directory.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following lines to your script:

```
import os
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

`__file__` will return the path of the script, and we can use `os.path.dirname` to find which directory it is located in. Then just use `os.chdir` to change to that directory.

Comment: Thanks, but it only works when you run the whole file, not in the interactive mode. It will throw the following error: 

    NameError: name '__file__' is not defined

Comment: IMO, in interactive mode, it only sees a few lines of code(not the script file), so it can't know where the script file is located at.